# Reordering nested arrays from JSON object based on key value

Tags: javascript, json

I made some JSON (as a string) but Javascript doesn't like its syntax when I try to pass it to JSON.parse. I can't understand what's wrong with it?

```
[
    {order: "2", targetUri: "http://www.google.com/"}, 
    {order: "1", targetUri: "http://www.bing.com/"}
]
```

And then how could I reorder the arrays based on the 'order' key? As in, turn it into a Javascript array which looks (something) like:

```
var someWebsites = [ 
                    {"order": "1", 
                     "targetUri": "http://www.bing.com/"}
                    {"order": "2", 
                     "targetUri": "http://www.google.com/"}
                   ];
```

Comment: Both input and output format seems to be invalid.

Comment: First question : Your are showing us an object and not a string thus `JSON.parse()` won't work + Your arrays are not valid. Second question: You cannot order an object

Comment: your json is invalid try this,

`[
   {order: "2", targetUri: "http://www.google.com/"}, 
   {order: "1", targetUri: "http://www.bing.com/"}
]`

Comment: Proverb: **Should be output is wrong, if input is wrong**

Comment: Thank you. I have amended the syntax based on your suggestions but it still won't JSON.parse. And I can assure you that the actual variable which is being passed to JSON.parse in my script is most definitely a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects, you could sort the array by taking `order` for sorting.

```js
var array = [
    { order: "2", targetUri: "http://www.google.com/" }, 
    { order: "1", targetUri: "http://www.bing.com/" }
];

array.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer seems to solve my ordering problem. I am yet to see if I can sort out my syntax/JSON.parse issues...